# Moving SpringBoot simple web service from Tomcat to Liberty doesn't recognize end point

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

With help from SpringInitializr, I've written a simple web service to recognize one endpoint "/hello".  When I build a .war on Gradle and run it, the service starts on (built-in) Tomcat and correctly responds to the URL "localhost:8080/hello".

I then copy the .war file to Liberty .../dropins/ and start the Liberty server; in Liberty's `server.xml`, the default port is 9080 rather than 8080.  When I hit the URL `localhost:9080/hello`, I get an error `Context Root not Found`.   When I hit the url `localhost:9080/UserSettingController/hello` (where the Java project name is `UserSettingController` I no longer get the `Context Root not Found` error but, instead, a 404 error.

Why does Tomcat recognize the endpoint but not Liberty?  Am I missing some Spring-ish connection?

The code for the project is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserSettingControllerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserSettingControllerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserSettingControllerApplication.class);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class RESTInterface {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, dude!";
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan( { "com.ui.usersetting.restinterface" } )

public class UserSettingControllerConfiguration {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug issues with Liberty in general, the log files can be found at `$SERVER_CONFIG_DIR/logs/` (for reference, the `server.xml` goes right inside `$SERVER_CONFIG_DIR`).  Without more detail, I can't provide a more concrete answer besides asking you to check in logs and report back what error your see.

However, I did try out your code in a .war packaged spring application, and the server started up fine and I was able to ping the hello endpoint at http://localhost:9080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello
Also, I used Liberty 18.0.0.1 (the latest GA release), so that may have helped too.

For reference, here is the server.xml I used:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
</server>
```

(The only things I changed from the default server.xml template was adding the `servlet-3.1` and `jaxrs-2.0` features)

Comment: I changed my server.xml as follows:   Change jsp-2.2 to jsp-2.3, added jaxrs-2.0, and change autoExpand from "false" to "true" and...  **it worked!**  Thanks, Andy.

Comment: great!  Do you know which of those things was the key piece that made it work?  Or was it a combination of all of them?

Comment: I *think* it was the autoExpand => "true".   It turned out, looking at the console.log, that I actually did not have those versions of the jsp and jaxrs features, but it seemed to work anyway.